# Perl - passing threads variable to subroutine to create it

Tags: perl, thread-safety, subroutine

I'm trying to create and later join a thread in the main part of the perl script, but create the thread in a subroutine, which takes parameters and adds some extra `xterm` parameters on to the command passed in. Would it be better to return the thread name (ID?)?

Here is the subroutine

```
sub run_thread{
  my $thread_name = $_[0];
  my $cmd = $_[1];
  $thread_name = threads->create({'void' => 1},
    sub { print("\n$cmd\n"); system($xterm . '-T "' . $cmd . '" -e ' . $cmd) });
}
```

and in main I'd like to call the sub like so:

```
my $thr1;    
run_thread($thr1, "pwd");
...
$thr1->join();
```

This doesn't work, and is probably wrong in some way on so many levels. Errors are:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at line 37.
Can't call method "join" on an undefined value at line 21.
```

I messed around with passing and returning by reference, but not sure on the best way. Please help.

Comment: create return an object, not a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant

```
sub run_thread {
   my (undef, $cmd) = @_;
   $_[0] = threads->create(...);
}

run_thread(my $thread, ...);
$thread->join();
```

(Assign to the parameter rather than the variable (`$thr`) into which the argument (undef) was copied.)

But why would you want to return a value through an argument? Makes far more sense to return it.

```
sub run_thread {
   my ($cmd) = @_;
   return threads->create(...);
}

my $thread = run_thread(...);
$thread->join();
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, returning the thread makes way more sense.
Why are you using @_ though? Did you mean $_[0]?

Comment: `@_` wouldn't work for me, it kept printing out the number of arguments. Perl 5.14.1

Comment: Then you didn't use what I posted. Specifically, you evaluated `@_` in scalar context, whereas I evaluate it in list context.

Comment: Ya, didn't realize the brackets were significant.

Comment: I looked at that link, and there is still one thing I do not understand: in what situations is it better to read `cmd` using `@_` instead of `$_[0]`?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Why did you use `@_` instead of `$_[0]` to capture the argument?

Comment: For consistency, because doing `my ($x, $y) = ($_[0], $_[1]);` would be silly.

Comment: In your second example, isn't `my ($cmd) = @_;` the equivalent of `my ($cmd) = $_[0];`. Did you mean to say `my (@cmd) = @_;`?

Comment: Functionally equivalent, yes, but I just gave you a reason why what I used is better. Another two is that `@_` is easier to read and type than `$_[0]`.